# Changing the state file permission

Tags: linux, file, permissions

I am using linux OS and I have been trying to replicate the file permissions into this state `-rwxrw-rw`

No matter how I tweaked the settings in the Permissions tab (right click on file >> Properties >> Permissions), I have been playing around with the `Access` and the `Execute`, and unfortunately whenever I use the command `ls -la` in terminal, I am never getting that particular file permission state that I wanted.

Additionally, I am also getting somewhat confused especially where the `x` factor is applicable whenever i choose Read and Write as the option, but I am unable to get rid of it should I use the same option for the next access.
I can only get either `-rw-rw-rw-` or `-rwxrwxrwx` as my result

Any ideas how I can replicate/ reproduce a file permission into this state `-rwxrw-rw` or should this can only be done via using the terminal only??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use: `chmod 766 yourfile` or if you have no permission try: `sudo chmod 766 yourfile`.

Comment: That works! I can see the difference is in the `Execute` has been changed into a hash instead of a tick. Whats the difference anyway? And I suppose this cannot be done via the UI method?

Comment: ok... but even so what exactly is the diff between ticked and hyphen? Tried googling for it but no avail results

Comment: I don't understand what are ticked and hyphen. Sorry for my poor English.